# C# Value does not fall within expected range during install

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

Reference Link To Tried Solutions: [Value does not fall within the expected range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284992/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range)

I realize this question has been asked before however none of the solutions have worked. I have an application that is programmed in C#. The program will debug just fine in Visual Studio 2015 Professional. However, when I publish the program and attempt to install on any computer I get the error "Value does not fall within expected range" and for the life of me I cannot figure this out.

Steps Taken To Resolve:

- Assured assemblies reference are set to copy = true
- Uninstalled and Re Installed program.
- Assured I am running as an administrator.

Log File

PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.14393.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1637.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file://fs01/Applications/EMS-Manager/emsdashboard.application
    Deployment Provider url     : file://fs01/Applications/EMS-Manager/emsdashboard.application
    Application url         : file://fs01/Applications/EMS-Manager/Application%20Files/emsdashboard_1_0_1_0/emsdashboard.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : emsdashboard.application, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity        : emsdashboard.exe, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of \fs01\Applications\EMS-Manager\emsdashboard.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Value does not fall within the expected range.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [4/4/2017 2:35:20 PM] : Activation of \fs01\Applications\EMS-Manager\emsdashboard.application has started.
    * [4/4/2017 2:35:20 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [4/4/2017 2:35:20 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [4/4/2017 2:35:20 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [4/4/2017 2:35:26 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [4/4/2017 2:35:26 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91, processorArchitecture=msil using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [4/4/2017 2:35:26 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
    * [4/4/2017 2:35:27 PM] : Downloading of subscription dependencies is complete.
    * [4/4/2017 2:35:27 PM] : Commit of the downloaded application has started.
    * [4/4/2017 2:35:28 PM] : Installation of application has successfully completed.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [4/4/2017 2:35:28 PM] System.ArgumentException
        - Value does not fall within the expected range.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    * Transaction at [4/4/2017 2:35:27 PM]
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: HQDW1NK6.GPQ.application
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
            - Status: Set
            - HRESULT: 0x0
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: emsdashboard.exe.manifest
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: emsdashboard.exe.config
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: ems-dashboard-app-icon.ico
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Resources\print-icon.png
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Resources\splash-screen-bg02.png
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Telerik.WinControls.GridView.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Telerik.WinControls.GridView.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Telerik.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Telerik.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Telerik.WinControls.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Telerik.WinControls.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Telerik.WinControls.RichTextEditor.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Telerik.WinControls.RichTextEditor.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Telerik.Reporting.Services.HttpClient.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Telerik.Reporting.Services.HttpClient.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Telerik.Reporting.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Telerik.Reporting.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: EMSDatabase.SL.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: EMSDatabase.SL.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Office2010Black.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Office2010Black.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: emsdashboard.exe.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: emsdashboard.exe
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Telerik.Reporting.XpsRendering.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Telerik.Reporting.XpsRendering.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Office2013Dark.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Office2013Dark.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: TelerikCommon.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: TelerikCommon.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationInstallDeployment
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - AppId: file://fs01/Applications/EMS-Manager/emsdashboard.application#emsdashboard.application, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
            - Status: Set
            - HRESULT: 0x0
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreTransactionOperationType (27)
            - HRESULT: 0x0
    * Transaction at [4/4/2017 2:35:28 PM]
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
            - Status: Set
            - HRESULT: 0x0
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationUninstallDeployment
            - Status: Uninstalled
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - AppId: file://fs01/Applications/EMS-Manager/emsdashboard.application#emsdashboard.application, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=cfc5547105e2f20e, processorArchitecture=x86
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
            - Status: Set
            - HRESULT: 0x0
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreTransactionOperationType (27)
            - HRESULT: 0x0

Comment: Make sure you don't have any mismatched version numbers on the Infragistics stuff, or any circular references. I.E. did you delete all of the references in your project to the Infragistics dll's and recreate the references so they point to the exact right version?

Comment: "None of the solutions have worked" - can you be more specific? What did you try, and what was the result? Can you at least link to the question you're referring to for context?

Comment: Sure, I have edited the question to include the reference link for solutions I've tried.

Comment: Make sure that you have no '&' in your deployment url.