# Handle all elements Holding event

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have an idea of implementing holding event handler for all text-type controls ( label, textbox, passwordbox, hyperlink etc. ) in order to show message popup for allowing suggest a better translation of this text.

Is it possible to implement such type of event handler for all controls that get added/removed from/to visual tree.

Without doing such for each element:

```
<TextBox Holding="HoldingEventHandler"/>
```

I have tried this in my MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
AddHandler(Control.HoldingEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(HoldingOccured), true);
```

But it fails with exception:

Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: After reading the following page I wonder if the error is really caused by your line above or if there's something else wrong with your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284992/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range

Comment: @dnickless all works if this line is commented our

Comment: I reckon, the HoldingEvent is something custom. Can we see its definition? - Pls ignore, hadn't seen the UWP tag. I thought we were talking WPF here. I'm sorry.

Comment: Does your Event Handler get called? What does the code for it look like? Have you got a stacktrace? Have you tried isolating your issue to the smallest possible example (create a new UWP project add only one textbox and the AddHandler statement - this should work in theory...)?

Comment: Try using `RightTapped` instead of `Holding`. You might want to support mouse at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement Holding in xaml and ask for new handler the system will generate the follow callback.

```
private void WindowsPage_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

So, thiis is a correct call parameters.

```
AddHandler(Control.HoldingEvent, new HoldingEventHandler(HoldingOccured), true);
```

Comment: Ah, nothing happened - the event handler doesn;t get called. i tried both - Control and UIElement